# How to instantiate multiple objects in area without intersection? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The task is to create a bunch of 3D prefabs with rigidbody and mesh colliders in specific box-shape area, so all of them would not be overlapping each other, after which they should fall to the surface beneath. If I set random position for each object, sometimes (especially if there are a lot of objects to create), some of them are being created too close to other, so they push each other while falling, and everything turns into a mess.

Is there a way to create these objects with at least minimal space between each other, so they could physically interact after they have fallen? Please, take into account, that spawning box is big enough to contain necessary amount of objects, no need in huge amount of them, but still the number of objects could be different each time.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make the box Collider smaller for instance if the object scale is (1,1,1) the collider would be (0.95f, 0.95f, 0.95f) or something similar. Of course only if you generate your cubes in a grid like system. After the first collision try to change the collider size again. If the problem persists try to make the colliders bigger and add a physics material with 0 friction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have big enough area for your objects, the dirtiest but the easiest solution (not meddling with bounding boxes etc.) would be to split the logic into two phases and using triggers to reposition the object randomly.

In the first phase, the generation phase, the object renderers are not active and the colliders are active.

1. Generate an object.
2. If the collider triggers an overlap and we are in the generation phase, reposition or respawn the object.

In the second phase, make renderers active and make them fall, disable colliders etc.